# promote artifacts using rest api /api/build/promote error unable to find artifacts of build

Tags: api, rest, build, artifactory

My payload is:

```py
payload = json.dumps({ "status": "staged", "comment": "testing.", "ciUser": "builder", "dryRun": "false", "targetRepo": "ext-release-local", "copy": "true", "artifacts": "true", "dependencies": "false", "scopes": [ "compile", "runtime" ], "properties": { "components": [ "c1", "c3", "c14" ], "release-name": [ "fb3-ga" ] }, "failFast": "true" })
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

I am trying

```py
response = requests.post(self.url+'/api/build/promote'+buildURL+'/2', payload, headers=headers, auth=('', ''))
```

getting error:

```
{"errors": [{"status": 400, "message": "Unable to find artifacts of build 'IT-GIS-ATS :: pmstack2 :: pm1-pm1' #2: aborting promotion."}]}
```

I do have 4-5 builds at this location which can be seen in artifactory Can you please help me on this.

Comment: sorry did not get you where do I find edit delete flag

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and the problem is not the promotion, but the publish. You have to make sure you add the following properties to the artifact, since that's how Artifactory links a build and an artifact:

```
build.name
build.job
build.number
build.timestamp # Not sure if this one is needed
```

Artifactory is a great product, but the documentation lacks a lot of detail.